# EndpointNotFoundException in client when connecting to a WCF named pipe service

Tags: wcf, named-pipes

I have two different processes (on the same session, both not elevated) that communicate using Named Pipes on a [self-hosted service](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/self-host) (hosted in the server process).
On rare conditions (2-3% of the users), the client will not be able to connect o the server.

It happens only under UAC and with no elevation. To be perfectly clear, in most cases the app works perfectly fine for users with UAC and not-elevated sessions.

I found out that running everything as an Administrator resolves this issue, but I do not want to go this road. Also, changing the communication to netTcp resolves it too, but it prompts my users the Windows Firewall dialog, which is unacceptable for me.

I can't figure out why this happens or how to resolve it. I saw many posts about permissions required to create pipes, but as I see it, I don't need a global pipe, just a local one, which should not require UAC off/elevation/specific objects.

The server will show no error and act normally, but the client will show this:

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/MyAppServices that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.DecodeFramingFault(ClientFramingDecoder decoder, IConnection connection, Uri via, String contentType, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at MyApp.BL.Interfaces.Service.IWCFClientServiceAPI.Initialize()
   at MyApp.Main.attemptConnection(WCFStoreAPIClient& i_WCFClientServiceAPI, IWCFClientCallbackAPI& i_WCFClientCallbackAPI)
```

Server config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="MyApp.Client.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="Locales"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netNamedPipeBinding>
        <binding name="NPBinding_IWCFClientServiceAPI" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" receiveTimeout="infinite" maxConnections="200" maxBufferSize="3145728" maxBufferPoolSize="3145728" maxReceivedMessageSize="3145728"/>
      </netNamedPipeBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service
          name="MyApp.Client.Core.Managers.WCFClientService"
          behaviorConfiguration="WCFClientServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/MyAppServices/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="MyApp.BL.Interfaces.Service.IWCFClientServiceAPI" bindingConfiguration="NPBinding_IWCFClientServiceAPI">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFClientServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Client config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netNamedPipeBinding>
        <binding name="NPBinding_IWCFClientServiceAPI" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" receiveTimeout="infinite" maxConnections="200" maxBufferSize="3145728" maxBufferPoolSize="3145728" maxReceivedMessageSize="3145728"/>
      </netNamedPipeBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/MyAppServices"
                binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NPBinding_IWCFClientServiceAPI"
                contract="MyApp.BL.Interfaces.Service.IWCFClientServiceAPI"
                name="NPBinding_IWCFClientServiceAPI">
        <headers>
          <ClientIdentification>MyAppStore</ClientIdentification>
        </headers>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Third party app breaks our WCF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981392/third-party-app-breaks-our-wcf-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem using named pipes for inter-process communication.  The client app could only connect to the server app when the server app was run using "run as administrator", otherwise I would get an `EndpointNotFoundException` from the client app.

This [post described the core of the problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fcb7254a-15b5-4be4-bf67-34d500bdce2d/wcf-netpipe-endpoint-not-found-exception-whitout-elevated-user-rights-uac-enabled).  If there is already a named pipe with an endpoint of `net.pipe://localhost/` created with elevated rights, clients will fail to connect to a non-elevated endpoint like `net.pipe://localhost/SomethingElse`.

This [post helped me find the named pipes](https://web.archive.org/web/20151116055104/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rodneyviana/archive/2011/03/22/named-pipes-in-wcf-are-named-but-not-by-you-and-how-to-find-the-actual-windows-object-name.aspx) that were open on my system.  Download the [Sysinternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx), then use Handle.exe from an elevated command prompt to search for opened named pipes.

```
handle net.pipe
```

The names of the pipes use Base64 Encoding.

```
net.pipe:E<Base64EncodedValue>
net.pipe:EbmV0LnBpcGU6Ly8rL1RSQURFU0VSVklDRS9TRVJWSUNFMS8=
```

I used this [link to decode the Base64 value](https://www.base64decode.org/).

```
bmV0LnBpcGU6Ly8rL1RSQURFU0VSVklDRS9TRVJWSUNFMS8=
net.pipe://+/TRADESERVICE/SERVICE1/
```

The named pipe that was causing the issue was

```
net.pipe:EbmV0LnBpcGU6Ly8rLw==
```

Which decoded to

```
net.pipe://+/
```

Note: + or * may be wildcards for localhost

Killing the offending process, or having it specify a more specific endpoint (like `net.pipe://localhost/SomethingElse`) resolved the issue.

Comment: Huh. I actually forgot about this issue.I ended up completely dropping WCF and moving to named pipes. You are correct though, the offending process was a part of Razer Synapse (Razer Wizard Service). Thanks.