# WCF: Net.Pipe – Endpoint not found exception – Admin/Non Admin mode

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, nettcpbinding

Our application uses WCF over named pipes to communicate between two processes of our application on same machine. Our application has been running in the multiple client fields without any issue for a couple of years now. But recently we have received issue from one client field is that due to presence of a one third party application at client side, our application is getting break.

When the 3rd party application is running at client side, the "service" side of our application process starts and has no problems creating the WCF endpoint. But when the "client" side" of our application process starts and attempts to connect to the "service" side, it fails with EndpointNotFoundException.

We are using endpoint address in format something like "net.pipe://localhost/TestAPI/Endpoint".

This post "[WCF named pipes unknown error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396603/wcf-named-pipes-unknown-error)" helped me to know the root cause of my issue. Through this post i knew, 3rd party application which was running at client side as a service in admin mode was opening the one endpoint address in format "net.pipe://localhost/".  At this point, when we killed the 3rd party application or run "service" side of our application process with admin mode without killing 3rd party application launched our application successfully.

Various links like mentioned below are available on internet which are talking about this issue but nither is given any fix for this issue:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ae114d6a-b6a6-4284-86c3-938e367a829c/using-netpipe-in-windows-8-nonadministrator?forum=wcf

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fcb7254a-15b5-4be4-bf67-34d500bdce2d/wcf-netpipe-endpoint-not-found-exception-whitout-elevated-user-rights-uac-enabled

[3rd party app breaks our WCF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981392/3rd-party-app-breaks-our-wcf-application/15987095#15987095)

Please give us fix of this problem how can "client" side" of our application process starts successfully without killing offending 3rd party application or without running our application "service" side process in admin mode?