# How to detect if a service is listening to global pipe net.pipe://localhost?

Tags: c#, wcf

According to this SO Q&A ([3rd party app breaks our WCF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981392/3rd-party-app-breaks-our-wcf-application/15987095#15987095)), it is possible to write a rogue service that listens to global WCF pipes using as base address net.pipe://localhost.

This has the side efect of preventing any local net.pipe://localhost/ endpoints to be reached by clients.

Is there any way to programmatically tell if a machine has a service running acting as an effective "catch all" for all WCF net pipes communications (global and local)?