# WCF netpipe created in non admin mode has connection issues

Tags: c#, wcf, ipc, named-pipes

I have created WCF netpipe connection on "**net.pipe://localhost/IBS**" which has an endpoint listening at "BasicService".

Creating this and hosting within my app is fine. But when I try to connect to this through "**net.pipe://localhost/IBS/BasicService**" this connection fails.

**It throws exception like following.**

```
There was no endpoint listening at **net.pipe://localhost/IBS/BasicService** that could accept the message. 
This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

While digging into this, I found that this connection failure happens only when the hosting app is running in non-admin mode. If I switch to admin mode the connection succeeds.

The issue happens because some other pipe is open on **net.pipe://localhost** in admin mode. So while my client tries to communicate to **net.pipe://localhost/IBS/BasicService** it ends up searching in **net.pipe://localhost** for **IBS/BasicService**. Where as i wanted it to search in **net.pipe://localhost/IBS** for **BasicService**.

Services running in admin mode is taking precedence. Is there a way in WCF to configure it other way or at-least after not finding at **localhost** it should try finding in **localhost/IBS** also.

Thanks.

Comment: what I can suggest but  I'm  not sure if it works  with  netpipe or not  is  to take a look  at failover in wcf in  this link   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778575/WCF-Routing-Service-Part-III-Failover-Load-Balanci

Comment: Fail over will not work in this case - reason being other alternate connection will also hit same issue. In fail over also all has to be net.pipe with some unique address created from non-admin. 
I saw in this post "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981392/3rd-party-app-breaks-our-wcf-application"
Discussion is around same area but no proper solution available. Actually microsoft should be fixing this. It's actually problem with WCF nat pipes itself.